# Rails 5 on Vagrant is caching classes in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running a bare-bones Rails 5 app on a Vagrant virtual machine. I've generated just one scaffold called Blog and it's working.

Any manual changes to the classes, however, require a Rails server restart in order to take effect, despite being in development mode.

***Edit: I've posted an answer to this that worked for me, after trying a lot of other flawed solutions, for those who want to skip ahead...***

The Blog scaffold files were all created successfully, I can view the pages using the index, edit, etc. routes. But if I change `@blogs = Blog.all` in the index method in `BlogsController` to `@blogs = Blog.limit(1)` and refresh the browser, the view doesn't change. All blog posts are still listed.

I looked in my local directory and the one on the vm. They match. So the changes are on the server.

I closed and restarted the Rails server with `@blogs = Blog.limit(1)` as the index method content, and the page loads as expected, with one blog post appearing.

How can I get the rails app to display updated content without restarting the server? Is there some caching going on by default that I can switch off? I'm using RubyMine as my IDE, but I don't have deployment settings in place and I haven't turned on any special caching. I've used RubyMine and Vagrant on another Rails project (running Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.1.4) without this issue.

**Rails version 5.2.3**

**Ruby version 2.4.1p111 or 2.6.3p62** (neither worked)

**RubyMine version 2019.1**

Vagrant is using VirtualBox and running **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**

According to other posts, this is the default behaviour for production environments. I tried `echo $RAILS_ENV` on the command line, but got back null.

I added `<%= Rails.env %>` to '...blogs/index.html.erb' and it shows 'development' in the browser. So the app environment is set correctly but it's still caching the classes (or something). Is there something about Rails 5 where it's treating the vm as a remote (production) server by default even though it's displaying 'development' as the Rails.env variable?

Here's the relevant console output after starting the rails server:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
 * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
 * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
 * Environment: development
 * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

**Things I've tried:**

- I've cleared the browser cache and run `rake tmp:cache:clear`. No
  effect.
- In the files 'config/environments/development.rb',
  'config/environments/test.rb', *and*
  'config/environments/production.rb' I set these attributes:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

and restarted the rails server. No effect.

- I've switched to Ruby version 2.6.3p62 from 2.4.1p111. No effect.
- I closed RubyMine and edited 'blogs_controller.rb' in SublimeText. No
  effect.
- I edited 'app/views/blogs/index.html.erb' and refreshed the browser
  window without restarting the server and the changes to the view are
  reflected immediately. So it's not an issue of caching *everything*.
- Added the following to my Vagrantfile in order to tighten the settings that sync the guest and host clock, and re-upped vagrant:

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.customize ["guestproperty", "set", :id, "--timesync-set-threshold", 5000] # Sync time every 5 seconds so Rails code reloads properly
    v.customize ["guestproperty", "set", :id, "--timesync-interval", 10000]     # Specifies interval at which to synchronize time with the host. Default is 10000ms (10 seconds).
    v.customize ["guestproperty", "set", :id, "--timesync-min-adjust", 100]     # The minimum absolute drift value measured in milliseconds to make adjustments for. The default is 1000 ms on OS/2 and 100 ms elsewhere.
    v.customize ["guestproperty", "set", :id, "--timesync-set-on-restore", 1]   # Set the time after the VM was restored from a saved state when passing 1 as parameter. This is the default.
end
```

No effect.

- Reinstalled Ruby, Rails, and all other gems. No effect.
- In Vagrantfile, Changed the file type for the synced folders that vagrant is using and set up a dhcp private network connection:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", mount_options: ['actimeo=1']
```

No effect.

- In Vagrantfile, ensured that the guest was getting the host clock data:

```
v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled", 0]
```

No effect.

This seems to be a similar issue, where the op is using Docker on Mac OS X: [Dockerized Rails 5 RC1 application not picking up updates to controllers and models in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144122/dockerized-rails-5-rc1-application-not-picking-up-updates-to-controllers-and-mod), but I'm not using any special deployment or provisioning, just a Vagrant vm.

This is another similar issue, but the configuration setting in the accepted answer doesn't exist in Rails 5: [Rails Server needs restart every time I make changes? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270945/rails-server-needs-restart-every-time-i-make-changes-why). One of the comments mentions an old issue where Vagrant guest and host clocks being out of sync could wreck Rails reloading. Going to investigate that possibility. *Edit: Tweaked the VirtualBox clock sync settings, confirmed that the clock on the guest and host were in sync (they're within 3 seconds when I run `date` on each machine - which still seems off, but they're close). Didn't work.*

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36616931/1512790

The file changes weren't being detected by `ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker`, no matter what changes I made to the clock sync, file types, etc.

The solution is: in 'config/environments/development.rb', replace this line

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

with this one:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

The FileUpdateChecker class, for whatever reason, works in vm environments when EventedFileUpdateChecker does not.

Huge shoutout to [pocari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5712918/pocari) for this solution.