# Rails doesn't detect file changes and config.reload_classes_only_on_change makes the server too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, ruby-on-rails-5, vagrantfile, rails-activestorage

First of all I don't know if this is a bug or not. Until now I've been using this command in rails development.rb environment config so the box detects changes on my files:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

But now, with Rails 5.2 and Active Storage that command makes the server a lot slower, and the images takes from 10 to 40sec to load.

Is it a bug? There is another way to make the vagrant/rails detect changes on my files without making me reload the server every time I change something?

Answer (score 10):

Solution:

After questioning the owner of the box I've been using, he gave me this alternative that works:

At the bottom of the `config/environments/development.rb` I did this change:

Find this line at the bottom of the file and comment out:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

Then add this line:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

So it looks like this:

```
# config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

Now it works properly and I do not have to use this command anymore:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true
```

Best regards!