# Why aren't changes to Rails files being reflected inside Docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm new to Rails and running a Rails app via Docker (on Windows/WSL2) and it seems any changes I make in controllers (and possibly elsewhere) are not reflected until I restart my container.

For example, if I delete the entire contents of a controller file, then refresh, there's no change. If I restart my container and then refresh, I get nice big red Rails errors, which is what I would expect.

What I've tried/checked:

1. That the right environment is being loaded - calling `Rails.env` on the Rails CLI (inside the container) yields "development"
2. That the `cache_classes` config option is set to `false` inside the `development.rb` environment file. I've also confirmed this via the Rails CLI via `Rails.application.config.cache_classes` - yields "false".

Here's my compose file (truncated):

```
  web:
    container_name: web
    env_file: .env
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid && gem install bundler -v 2.2.21 && bundle install && rails db:migrate && rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5432:5432
      - 2222:2222
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    profiles:
      - app
      - appnm
```

Anyone see what's up?

Comment: Are you using Windows and WSL2 on your host machine?

Comment: Yes - Docker on Windows via WSL2.

Comment: It might be this issue where file change notifications don't get sent to the container, then: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739 See if you can get your container to look for file changes by polling the file system

Comment: `../:/app` -- why two dots here?

Comment: Because my Docker config is in a child directory of the app root.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks but it turned out to be a Rails-specific issue. Posting solution shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed to change the following in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

to

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

Why this isn't in the development env file by default, I've no idea. Surely the whole point of a development environment is to allow high-frequency file edits be reflected in the app as they happen!

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50640007/1352288).